# AngularJS - Unable to define controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. Does anyone know why I am getting this error - `Argument 'activationCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

HTML -

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="member" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Member</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="memberId" placeholder="Member" ng-click = "activation.zipcode()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller -

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('activationCtrl', activationCtrl);

  function activationCtrl() {   
    var self = this;

self.zipCode = function() {
        console.log("zipcode");
}
  }
```

State -

```
.when('/activation', {
        templateUrl: 'views/activation.html',
        controller: 'activationCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'activation'
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I thkink the problem could be in the wrong order of controller's and state's definitions. You need to define controller before state (route), so you can use it there.</s>

Alternitavely you can skip controller registration in module and just define it as a separate function with `$inject` property and pass this function in state (route) definition. E.g.:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('app')
  .config([$routeProvider, function($routeProvider) {
      routeProvider
        .when('/activation', {
          templateUrl: 'views/activation.html',
          controller: activationCtrl,
          controllerAs: 'activation'
        })
}]);

function activationCtrl() {   
  var self = this;
  self.zipCode = function() {
    console.log("zipcode");
  }
}
activationCtrl.$inject = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your angular controller to the HTML like so:

use `ng-controller="activationCtrl"`

try putting that in the body tag of your html page:

`<body ng-controller="activationCtrl">`

Comment: In given case it's not neccessary to add an ng-controller directive anywhere, as in the code above controller is set in template definition.

Answer (score 0):

Argument 'activationCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Above error comes when you define controller , but you do not import activationCtrl.js file in you html .